# Deploy software to Azure from AzureDevOps with YAML files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a question about deploying to different environments (Test / Production) with one pipeline.

In this scenario I have a test and production environment. With the same configuration for deploying web application to Azure for two countries. In the current situation we have a release pipeline in the production and test with two stages. One stage for country A and one stage for country B.

What I did is as follows:

1. I created an variable group (with Azure key vault).
2. I created an deployment YAML file for my stages / steps.
3. In that deployment YAML file I am reffering to the variables.yml file.
4. My deployment YAML file has two stages.

   - First stage for country A
   - Second stage for country B
5. Both of the stages are using the same steps but different description and CosmosDB container etc..

What I want to do is:

1. Using one stage in the deployment YAML.
2. Using two variables.yml, one for each country.
3. Depending on wether it is country A or B, pointing to the correct variables.yml file so it can make use of the correct values.

The same goes for the production and test environment. depending on the environment, I want to be able to point to the correct YAML variables.yml.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @AlvinZhao thank you for your time and answer. I was looking for something similar, it is close to what I was looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what obstructed your design pipeline, however, based on your current requirements, the YAML pipeline structure was straightforward. Since you have two variables template `.yml` files, you can import diffrent templates in respective deployment jobs and each deployment can be configured to run against its corresponding environment.

```
# Your used to deploy web apps via release pipeline, so assumed there was already a pipeline resource that generated build artifacts. To use that build artifact from the pipeline resource below:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildWebApp
    project: TheProjectName
    source: ThePipelineName

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy to Azure Web Apps
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJobA
    displayName: Deploy to Production - Country A
    variables:
    - template: variablesA.yml
    environment: Prod
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: BuildWebApp
            displayName: Download artifacts for deployment from the pipeline resource
          - script: |
              echo "ARM Service Connetion for deployment is $(ARMSvcCnnName)"
              echo "Azure Web App name is $(AzureWebAppName)"
            displayName: Check the variable values in variables.yml
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnnName)'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: '$(AzureWebAppName)'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
  
  - deployment: DeploymentJobB
    displayName: Deploy to Test - Country B
    variables:
    - template: variablesB.yml
    environment: Test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: BuildWebApp
            displayName: Download artifacts for deployment from the pipeline resource
          - script: |
              echo "ARM Service Connetion for deployment is $(ARMSvcCnnName)"
              echo "Azure Web App name is $(AzureWebAppName)"
            displayName: Check the variable values in variables.yml
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnnName)'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: '$(AzureWebAppName)'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

[image]

Even though the variable names in each template are the same, since the two templates `variablesA.yml` and `variablesB.yml` work for respective deployment job scope, the variable values are different during runtime.